Client is Closed
i keep having the client is closed operation
i checked the documentations and i added "client.connect()' the error went didn't show up but my api responses weren't coming through i asked gpt and according to it the line i added was the issue.


const client = redis.createClient();
client.connect();

client.on("error", function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});



const setJWT = (key, value) => {
  console.log(typeof key,typeof value)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return client.set(key, value, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};

const getJWT = (key) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      client.get(key, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });  
};  

const deleteJWT = (key) => {  
  try {  
    client.del(key);  
  } catch (error) {  
    console.log(error);  
  }  
};  
module.exports = {  
  setJWT,  
  getJWT,  
  deleteJWT,  
};  

when i tried the await method it's the same issue

The .connect method is also asynchronous. So, you need to put an await there. Also, the order is wrong on these calls and you need to set up the event handler first:
const client = redis.createClient();
await client.connect();

client.on("error", function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});

And you need to use await instead of callbacks when you are invoking Redis commands. The callbacks are for older versions of Node Redis and, while they are technically supported, they're there for supporting old code, not for new development. And, frankly, it's not the direction the Node Redis—or JavaScript for that matter—is heading:
const result = await client.get(key);

Hope this helps and best of luck!
